# How to stop a tap from counting when the timer is paused in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitouch

I am designing an iphone app that basically lets the user tap a ball on screen and the app counts how many times the user taps the ball, the problem is, the app counts the taps from before the start button is tapped.  How would I stop the taps from counting toward your score before the start button is tapped?

Here is my code:

.h:

```
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Ball1;
    NSTimer *mainTimer1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *startButton1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *currentNumber1;
    IBOutlet UIButton *pause1;
    UIAlertView *alertStart1;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIImageView *Ball1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  NSTimer *mainTimer1;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  UIButton *startButton1;

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startMove;
- (void)moveBall;
- (BOOL)Intersecting:(CGPoint)loctouch:(UIImageView *)enemyimg;
- (IBAction)pause1:(id)sender;
- (void)alertStart1;

@end
```

.m:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
// if user touched ball, stop timer 
if ([self Intersecting:location :Ball1]) {
    [mainTimer1 invalidate];
    mainTimer1 = nil;
    startButton1.hidden = NO;
    number++;
    [currentNumber1 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number]];
    }
}   

-(BOOL)Intersecting:(CGPoint)loctouch:(UIImageView *)enemyimg {
CGFloat x1 = loctouch.x;
CGFloat y1 = loctouch.y;

CGFloat x2 = enemyimg.frame.origin.x;
CGFloat y2 = enemyimg.frame.origin.y;
CGFloat w2 = enemyimg.frame.size.width;
CGFloat h2 = enemyimg.frame.size.height;

if ((x1>x2)&&(x1<x2+w2)&&(y1>y2)&&(y1<y2+h2))
    return YES;
else
    return NO;

}

-(void)moveBall {
CGFloat xdist = fabs(Destination.x-Ball1.center.x);
CGFloat ydist = fabs(Destination.y-Ball1.center.y);

if ((xdist<5)&&(ydist<5)) { 
    Destination = CGPointMake(arc4random() % 320, arc4random() % 480);
    xamt = ((Destination.x - Ball1.center.x) / speed);
    yamt = ((Destination.y - Ball1.center.y) / speed);
} else {
    Ball1.center = CGPointMake(Ball1.center.x+xamt, Ball1.center.y+yamt);
}
}

-(IBAction)startMove {
startButton1.hidden = YES;

Destination = CGPointMake(arc4random() % 320, arc4random() % 480); 
xamt = ((Destination.x - Ball1.center.x) / speed);
yamt = ((Destination.y - Ball1.center.y) / speed);

mainTimer1 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.02) target:self selector:@selector(moveBall) userInfo:nil repeats: YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the method

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

put a check to see if the game has begun, e.g.

```
if (startButton1.hidden) {
    // game has begun, add points
} else {
    // game hasn't yet begun, don't add points
}
```

Comment: This is the approach you want. However, I'd recommend using a state variable (BOOL shouldCountPoints) to check whether you should add points or not- there might be a case down the road where the button is not hidden but for some reason you want to count points.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is gonna be for iOS 3.2+, use `UITapGestureRecognizer` instead of `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and then when the user press the start button add the recognizer to the imageView. Also remember to set the userInteractionEnabled to YES of the UIImageView in order to use UIGestureRecognizer's on them.